# Rails 4.2 + Paperclip + Amazon s3: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Even though this error it is present in other SO questions, I've not been able to work arround so I'm seeking for help.

I'm using `rails 4.2.5`, `paperclip ~>4.1`, `aws-sdk <2.0` to store attached files into `Amazon S3`.

I've creadted a `bucket` and a `IAM User` who has `AmazonS3FullAccess` permissions and with his credentials I'm trying to connect from Rails like this.

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => 'bucket-name',
    :access_key_id => '****',
    :secret_access_key => '****',
  }
}
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
  :styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100#" }, 
  :default_url => "/img/avatar-missing.jpg",
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => "s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

I configured the bucket permissions with this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to upload something to it, it throws me this ******* error:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

In the console I can see that paperclip is able to resize the picture but it is not able to upload it to Amazon S3

```
[paperclip] saving /users/avatars/000/000/001/original/10382845_246916218831306_3480489092212800336_n.jpg
[AWS S3 200 2.304022 3 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"bucket-name",:content_length=>41431,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: 10382845_246916218831306_3480489092212800336_n.jpg,:key=>"users/avatars/000/000/001/original/10382845_246916218831306_3480489092212800336_n.jpg") SocketError getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to configure the model like this:

```
  has_attached_file :my_file,
    :storage => :s3,
    :default_url => "/default.default",
    :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :region => ENV['AWS_REGION']
    }
```

sometimes the issue is that a region is not defined and the configuration fails.

Comment: Thanks man. This can be moved into the initializer too. The key (with this gems versions) is to declare `:s3_region` in the **paperclip_defaults** hash, and `:region` in the **:s3_credentials** hash. Thank you very much, I lose a lot of time fighting this.